# No devuelve la consulta Django Postgresql al listar

Tags: django

apps.urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('nuevo/', empleado_view, name='nuevo'),
    path('listar/', empleado_list, name='listar'),

 ]
```

apps.views

```
 def empleado_view(request):
        if request.method =='POST':
            form = EmpleadoForm(request.POST)
            #CODIGO PARA DETECTAR ERRORES EN LA CAPTURA DE DATOS ANTES DE if form.is_valid()
            for field, errors in form.errors.items():
                print('Field: {} Errors: {}'.format(field, ','.join(errors)))
            form.is_valid()
            print(form.errors)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
            return redirect('empleados:listar')
        else:
            form = EmpleadoForm()
        return  render(request, 'empleados/empleados_form.html', {'form':form})




    def empleado_list(request):
        empleado = Empleado.objects.order_by('apell1Emp')
        contexto = {'empleado': empleado}
        return render(request, 'empleados/empleados_list.html', contexto)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El formulario de ingresos funciona bien, pero las vistas me sale en blanco solo encabezado. no se que me esta pasando, alguna ayuda, alguien puede darme alguna mano, sugerencias.

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y plantea tu problema **detalladamente** para ayudarte con mayor facilidad y de ser posible adjunta el código HTML de los templates que renderisan las vistas que muestras en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Desde el template estas tratando de recorrer la variable **object_list** pero desde la vista estas pasando al contexto la variable **empleado**

te debería quedar algo asi

```
def empleado_list(request):
    empleado = Empleado.objects.order_by('apell1Emp')
    contexto = {'object_list': empleado}
    return render(request, 'empleados/empleados_list.html', contexto)
```

Comment: Hice el ajuste, pero ahora me da errror, django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'list' not found. 'list' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: ¿ Hiciste algún cambio en el template ? da ese error porque en alguna parte estás generando una url con el nombre 'list', imagino que se debería llamar 'listar' como aparece en tu archivo urls.py